# How does the Google Calendar app determine which images to show me for the seasons?

Tags: calendar, geolocation, google-calendar

The Google Calendar app for Android has these illustrations for each month:

[image]

[image]

They fit my current location (northern Europe) very well, but if I was in the southern hemisphere (where the seasons are opposite from here) or the tropics, they would not fit.

I'm guessing that these images may change based on the user's location. If that's the case (which I realize it may not be), then how does the app determine this? Is it based on the geolication of the Android device, or the country of the Google Account the user is using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are independent of the location. I live in India and see exactly the same images as you posted for those months in question. Very few parts of the country experience snow and definitely not where I live. [Wiki on Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Calendar) also didn't mention that these are location based and it appears universal. These images [can't be disabled too](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/ELOxs5cyYjc)

Only the holiday calendar is country specific

Comment: Wow. That's pretty bad design by Google.

Comment: Yes and as you would see in the linked page, for three years now folks are requesting that these images spill the professional look of Calendar, it appears childish, and more importantly clashes with user colour costumes of events

Comment: To be fair, India is in Northern Hemisphere. These images may not be a perfect fit for all seasons in India but they're still not exactly opposite as in case of Southern Hemisphere.

Comment: @kalehv Yes, you make a valid point